# Python +pyodbc Retrieving images from MSSQL data. HOW to?

Tags: python, sql-server, image, pyodbc

Sorry I don't show any piece of code here but I simply don't know how to start?

Ok I simply selected image cell and got file of bytearray:

"[bytearray(b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1\x1a1Exif\x00\x00II*\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x08\x01\x00\ (...) etcetc )]"

But how to transform it and save as image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
from PIL import Image
import os,io
.....
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(my_bytearray))
image.save(path_to_image)
```

PIL must be installed separately by
pip -m install pillow (I'm not certain if -m is necessary ;) )